# Postegre SQL. Как преобразовать временной интервал в количество месяцев

Tags: postgresql

примерный запрос:

```
SELECT id_tech, max(dt::date) - min(dt::date)  AS lifetime
FROM p.tech 
GROUP BY id_tech
HAVING  max(dt) - min(dt) <> 0
```

Итогом этого запроса является количество дней

пробовал EXTRACT(MONTH FROM (max(dt::date) - min(dt::date))) к сожалению не работает

Comment: Вычесть годы, умножить на 12. Вычесть месяцы, прибавить. Сравнить дни, при необходимости подкорректировать на единичку.

Comment: Мне кажется есть более короткий способ)

Comment: В постгрессе? может, и есть - но не знаю, не видел...